# how to solve image type 'unknown' error typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey sorry for the bad english I hope you guys understand what I mean. I have this code below but I get error and `image` is of type `unknown`.

Do you guys know how to solve this error? please tell me how to solve this error and please do tell me in detail what need to change or add because I am really new to typescript

```
const createImage = (url:any) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(image));
        image.addEventListener("error", error => reject(error));
        image.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous"); // needed to avoid cross-origin issues on CodeSandbox
        image.src = url;
      });



   
    function getRadianAngle(degreeValue:any) {
      return (degreeValue * Math.PI) / 180;
    }

export default async function getCroppedImg(imageSrc:any, pixelCrop:any,rotation = 0) {
  const image = await createImage(imageSrc);
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (!ctx) {
    return;
  }
 
  const maxSize = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
  const safeArea = 2 * ((maxSize / 2) * Math.sqrt(2));


canvas.width = safeArea;
  canvas.height = safeArea;

  ctx.translate(safeArea / 2, safeArea / 2);
  ctx.rotate(getRadianAngle(rotation));
  ctx.translate(-safeArea / 2, -safeArea / 2);

ctx.fillStyle = "#DCDCDC";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.drawImage(
    image
    safeArea / 2 - image.width * 0.5,
    safeArea / 2 - image.height * 0.5
  );
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, safeArea, safeArea);


canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;

  // paste generated rotate image with correct offsets for x,y crop values.
  ctx.putImageData(
    data,
    Math.round(0 - safeArea / 2 + image.width * 0.5 - pixelCrop.x),
    Math.round(0 - safeArea / 2 + image.height * 0.5 - pixelCrop.y)
  );


  return new Promise(resolve => {
    canvas.toBlob(file => {
      resolve(file);
    }, "image/png");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to type the return of `Promise`, otherwise it will becomes `unknown`:

```
const createImage = (url: string) =>
    new Promise<HTMLImageElement>((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
    });
```

and also in the last line:

```
return new Promise<Blob | null>(resolve => {
        canvas.toBlob(file => {
            resolve(file);
        }, "image/png");
    });
```